# How to make carousel go around?

Tags: jquery

I have a carousel and it works well if you go left or right.
But i want it to loop instead of stop one way. I have got it to loop fine if the right hand arrow is clicked. But cant seem to work out the left hand.

script:

```
  $('.carousel-next-page').click(function () {
        var carousel = $(this).parents('.carousel').find('ul');
        var scroll = carousel.scrollLeft();
        var w = carousel.width();
        var x = 0;
        carousel.find('li').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).position().left < w) {
                x = $(this).position().left;
            }
            if ($(this).position().left < 0) {
                carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 'fast');
                return false;
            }
           // alert("this position = " + $(this).position().left + ", Width = "+ w + ", x = " + x)
        });
        carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: scroll + x }, 'fast');
        return false;
    });
    $('.carousel-prev-page').click(function () {
        var carousel = $(this).parents('.carousel').find('ul');
        var scroll = carousel.scrollLeft();
        var w = carousel.width();
        var x = 0;
        carousel.find('li').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).position().left < 1 - w)
            {
                x = $(this).position().left;
            }

            //if ($(this).position().left > 0) {
            //    carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: carousel.find('li:last').position().left }, 'fast');
            //    return ;
            //}               

        });
        if (x == 0) {
            carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 'fast');
        } else {
            carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: scroll + x }, 'fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">        
       <div class="float-left" style="margin-top:25px;">                
            <a href="#" class="carousel-prev-page"><span><img src="/gfx/smallLeftArrow.png" alt=""></span></a>
       </div>
       <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/a8902970-b083-4bc7-a05d-eb296771ffd0.png">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/59af2104-c73d-4f1f-91c6-476c1da47420.png">
                </li>                    

                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/f225100a-d8bf-4dc9-b552-01db65c110b3.png">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/7efbf5d5-fcdd-4127-b8cf-5a36d5a507a8.png">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/b1b9184f-aaed-4658-9fbe-5fc3b86975d1.png">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/a3b493b5-6302-44f8-83e0-2a3a060013e6.png">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/slideshow/cac1b555-e155-48d8-960f-00d25eaf2dde.png">
                </li>
       </ul>
        <div class="float-left" style="margin-top:25px;">              
              <a href="#" class="carousel-next-page"><span><img src="/gfx/smallRightArrow.png" alt=""></span></a>
       </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.carousel ul { overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; position:relative; width:700px; float:left; }

.carousel li { display:inline-block; }   

.carousel-prev-image, .carousel-next-image, .carousel-prev-page, .carousel-next-page
{
    width: 15px;
    height: 25px;
}

.carousel-prev-image, .carousel-prev-page
{
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.carousel-next-image, .carousel-next-page
{
    margin-right:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out!

```
     $('.carousel-prev-page').click(function () {
        var carousel = $(this).parents('.carousel').find('ul');
        var scroll = carousel.scrollLeft();
        var w = carousel.width();
        var x = 0;
        var beggining = false;
        carousel.find('li').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).position().left < 1 - w)
            {
                x = $(this).position().left;
            }         
            if ($(this).position().left == 0)
            {
                beggining = true;
            }
        });
        //alert(x);
        if (beggining) {
            carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: carousel.find('li:last').position().left }, 'fast');
            return false;
        }
        else if (x == 0) {
            carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 'fast');
        } else {
            carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: scroll + x }, 'fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is first put your next and previous methods into their own functions:

```
function nextSlide() { ... }
function prevSlide() { ... }
```

Edit: I had at first thought you were wanting to make them automatically loop. This first step isn't actually necessary, but would make the functions easily reusable.

...then give each `.carousel` element a `data-*` attribute and loop based on that:

```
var slideNumber = 1;

// Loop through each carousel 'slide' adding a data-slide attribute
$('.carousel ul li').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-slide', slideNumber++);
})
```

...set the current 'initial' slide:

```
var currentSlide = 1;
```

...then in your function to change slide, determine the next and prev slide (where slideNumber is now the total number of slides (list items in your carousel)):

```
var nextSlide = (currentSlide + 1) >= slideNumber ? 1 : currentSlide + 1;
var prevSlide = (currentSlide - 1) < 1 ? slideNumber - 1 : currentSlide - 1;
```

...then set the position of the next or previous list item (depending on which way you want your slider to loop):

```
$('.carousel ul li[data-slide="' + nextSlide + '"]').css({left:'100%'});
$('.carousel ul li[data-slide="' + prevSlide + '"]').css({left:'-100%'});
```

...then proceed with the slide change by calling the functions on click.

Let me just make a JSFiddle for this.

Edit: [Here is the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/25jPe/). You'll need to prevent the previous and next buttons being clicked before the animation is complete to prevent it from breaking.

Comment: this does it one slide at a time, i currently display 6 lis?

Comment: I need six images to be displayed and then scroll to next 6 and then next 6 ans then so on?

Comment: You didn't state that in your initial question. Either way, my answer is still valid here. The best way to achieve this would be to have 6 images per slide. Simply store the 6 images within one of these list items.

Comment: sorry, Erm the list items are dynamic

Comment: It wouldn't be logical to have 6 images all sliding out at the same time individually. If it isn't possible to wrap every 6 list items in their own individual list then you can use jQuery to modify the HTML. Then simply turn each list into a slide rather than the list items.

Comment: Isn't there some way to check that it is at the end of the list and just go back to the beginning when next is clicked and vice versa with previous

Comment: see edit i have worked out how to do it for next just not previous

Comment: The problem is that you're wanting 6 images sliding independently of each other, and then a new set of 6 images sliding independently into their place. You'd need some sort of container for this to be manageable - that way instead of sliding all 6 images individually you're simply sliding the container of the 6 images (which can be done with the example I've provided). My example shows the basis of how you could loop around when getting to the end. In order to get this to work for 6 independent images you'll need to put some further math into it and loop through each of the 6 images per slide.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24506/discussion-between-beginner-and-james-donnelly)

Answer (score 0):

Its basically operating on inline divs

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="slide_container"><div class="slide">4</div><div class="slide">5</div><div  class="slide">6</div><div class="slide">1</div><div class="slide">2</div><div class="slide">3</div></div></div>
<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">Right</button>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{height:60px;width:200px;border:gray solid 10px;background:#ccc;overflow:hidden}
.slide_container{margin-left:-600px;height:60px;width:4000px}
.slide{background:#aaa;height:60px;width:200px;display:inline-block;}
```

JS

```
var slider = function(dir){
if(dir==1){
    $('.slide_container .slide:first').animate({'width':0},200,function(){$(this).appendTo($('.slide_container')).removeAttr('style');});

}else if(dir==-1){
    $('.slide_container .slide:last').css('width',0).prependTo($('.slide_container ')).animate({'width':200},200,function(){$(this).removeAttr('style');});
}
}

$('#left').click(function(){slider(1)});
$('#right').click(function(){slider(-1)});
```

Comment: this is fine with one li on the screen, but what i have is 6 and then all 6 shift and can be different lengths

Comment: ideally instead of having to re-code alot i would just like someone to help work out how to just make the left button click

Comment: If you'd see the EDIT portion, that fiddle has 6 li running parallel !